# Eclipse Watchpoint

Tags: eclipse

I would like to setup a watchpoint on a field

```
final RenderingContext renderingContext = renderingEngine.getRenderingContext();
```

I am able to setup a breakpoint but not a watchpoint. I would like to debug the execution when this field renderingContext is equal something.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's final, so it's always that one value. There's nothing to watch. What you're asking about is a Conditional Breakpoint, which just means that you need to set a Condition on the Breakpoint you've created. When the expression you enter is `true`, it'll stop. Right-click on the Breakpoint to set the condition.

Comment: Thanks @nitind. Can the conditional for the breakpoint have any variables from the class.

Comment: Anything that line's scope has access to, I believe.

Comment: Does the variable exist before you execute that line of code? You can't use it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @nitind
The solution was to use variable.equals("string") in the conditional.